# Sorting data from database, to use in chart. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I am using highcharts for showing charts on my website. I have a database table, named "advertisement_clicks". I want the data from that table, to go into a highchart. **but**, I want the data to seperate when a new day come.

A picture of my database: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cfia2md0

The way to put the # of clicks (# of rows found) in the highchart is this way:

```
    series: [{
                name: 'Clicks',
                data: [1, 2, 3]
            }],
```

The way to set the day in highcharts is in this way:

```
 xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Today', '09-06', '10-06']
                },
```

**I want to limit the data, by X number of days.**

I was thinking of doing it with Arrays, but I am just not sure how to. Please help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of days by filtering on date column, ie `WHERE 'date' BETWEEN x AND y` and to get data for days use `GROUP BY 'date'`. So your query would be something like

```
SELECT
  count(id) AS Clicks,
  date AS categories
FROM advertisement_clicks
WHERE date BETWEEN x AND y
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Replace `x` and `y` with the date range you want to create chart for.

Or if you really want always query for `x` **last** days then use (assuming mySQL)

```
date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL x DAY
```

in the `WHERE` instead of `date BETWEEN x AND y`.

In case the `date` column is infact timestamp you must extract the date part for grouping, ie assuming mySQL `GROUP BY DATE(date)`

Format the date in the client side (for "categories" label), it would be easier than to do it in SQL (althought most engines support date formating functions).

Comment: Wouldn't that only aggregate clicks which occurred at the exact same timestamp? I think you need to do both your date handling and the aggregation in sql or in the client, rather than split across the two.

Comment: I assume that the `date` column contains only date, if it is timestamp then indeed the date part must be extracted for grouping.

Comment: His screenshot shows what looks like a raw unix timestamp as the date column.

Comment: Right. However, if the timestamps don't contain time part (ie all are marking midnight) then grouping by them is OK :) The column name implies date only so thats what I went with...